How to ignore pyarrow timestamp cast error in polars
I am reading a delta table using pl.read_delta() and for a particular table I am returning and error ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[us, tz=UTC] would lose data: in pandas you can do pq.read_table('path').to_pandas(safe=False)
I am just trying to find an equivalent option. I know you can pass in pyarrow_options to pl.read_delta() but I can't find what all the options are available for that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried searching for all the options in the polars documentation and the pyarrow documentation but could not find anything that would help me with the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You could do it like this. In my example, I write a pandas dataframe to a delta table first, just to set the scence
import pandas as pd
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake
import polars as pl
from deltalake import DeltaTable


data = {
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=5, freq='T'),
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

write_deltalake('delta_table', df)



delta_path = 'delta_table'
delta_table = DeltaTable(delta_path)
arrow_table = delta_table.to_pyarrow_table()

pandas_df = arrow_table.to_pandas(safe=False)
polars_df = pl.from_pandas(pandas_df)

print(polars_df)


which returns
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 10    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ 20    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 30    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ 40    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:04:00 ┆ 50    │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘

Update: Excluding pandas apart for the creation of the table for the example
To exclude pandas:
import pandas as pd
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake
from deltalake import DeltaTable
import polars as pl

data = {
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=5, freq='T'),
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

write_deltalake('delta_table', df)

delta_path = 'delta_table'
delta_table = DeltaTable(delta_path)
arrow_table = delta_table.to_pyarrow_table()

polars_df = pl.from_arrow(arrow_table)
print(polars_df)

which returns

shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 10    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ 20    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 30    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ 40    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:04:00 ┆ 50    │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘


Thank you for your response. This is a nice start but really I am looking to accomplish this without the use of pandas.

The only reason I used pandas was to create the file. The rest does not involve pandas.

Oh! I apologize. Maybe I am misunderstanding. Does this line not require pandas pandas_df = arrow_table.to_pandas(safe=False)?

@user23406368 Updated my answer with a solution excluding pandas (apart for the creation for the table for the sake of the example).

Hey Serge the solution you provided still produces the error I am trying to avoid. Since the casting is not "safe" I continue to get the same error. PyArrow is still trying to cast the timestamps and is resulting in the following error:
ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[us, tz=UTC] would lose data: 7907844873709551616
